# SQL - Order by ascending date difference from NOW()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to formulate a seemingly simple SQL query where I join two tables and order the results by the date difference from one of the columns and `NOW()`.

I am trying the query:

```
SELECT advertise_id, 
       qr_startdate,
       qr_enddate, 
       DATEDIFF(day, NOW(), t1.qr_enddate) AS d 
FROM `adv_qr` t1 
INNER JOIN advertise_table t2 
    ON t1.advertise_id = t2.lid 
ORDER BY t1.d ASC
```

Which seems like it should be right, but clearly something in the syntax is incorrect. I've been trying various combinations of things, but can't seem to get the `DATEDIFF` to return in a way that I can order the results with it.

Comment: Try including the 'day' column in the select and giving it an alias.  Day is a keyword and might be an issue.
edit:  Yea, I think it should be datediff( now(), otherday)

Comment: Since 'd' is an alias, does it need to have the t1 in front of it?  It is not a member of the t1 table...

Comment: @Tommy: You're right. I removed the t1 in the ORDER BY and the SQL executes when I also use @Alden's suggestion of using `datediff( now(), otherday)` However, my `d` column is `NULL`. And of course that makes the `ORDER BY` irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT advertise_id, 
       qr_startdate,
       qr_enddate, 
       DATEDIFF(NOW(), t1.qr_enddate) AS d 
FROM `adv_qr` t1 
INNER JOIN advertise_table t2 
    ON t1.advertise_id = t2.lid 
ORDER BY d ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/754de/8):

```
SELECT advertise_id, 
       qr_startdate,
       qr_enddate, 
       DATEDIFF(NOW(), t1.qr_enddate) AS d 
 FROM `adv_qr` t1 
 INNER JOIN advertise_table t2 
    ON t1.advertise_id = t2.lid 
 ORDER BY d ASC
```

You can find the MySQL [`DATEDIFF` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/date-and-time-functions.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a direct subtraction?

```
NOW() - t1.qr_enddate
```

as the sort criterion?